# Reading an API which is returning StreamingResponseBody as response

Tags: java, ios, angularjs, spring-boot, streaming

I have an API which is returning huge data ( > 7 MB) in JSON format. An IOS device is accessing this API and storing data in to local device storage. Since response size is huge, user is experiencing long delay.

I created another API with same data but this time I have used StreamingResponseBody to write output directly to the response object as stream. Now response size reduced to 2 MB. But how client device (IOS/Angular) can read the response? Because when I hit the API from postman the output is not readable.

Here is the controller code -

```
@GetMapping( value = "/materials/stream")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getMaterialsStreamed() {

        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
            try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream)) {
                oos.writeObject(service.getMaterials()); // service.getMaterials() is returning Iterable<Material>
            }
        };

        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=generic_file_name.json")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).body(responseBody);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a stream of bytes, postman will just print it as bytes(which is unreadable). you need to save the stream first and then read it as a normal file(i.e downloading a file and open it using IOS/Angular).